Sequences with constant cross-ratio
The cross ratio for four collinear points $\left(A,B,C,D\right)$ is defined as $\frac{(AC)(BD)}{(AD)(BC)}=\frac{(AB+BC)(BC+CD)}{(AB+BC+CD)BC}$ i.e. it is a function of the three lengths $AB,BC,CD$
if we now define $AB:=y[0],\,BC:=y[1],\,CD:=y[2]$ a natural question is for explicit formulas for the sequences with constant cross-ratio for every triplet of contiguous values given three initial values.
A recursive definition is easily derived:
$y[i]=\frac{y[i-3]\,y[i-1]^2}{y[i-3]\,y[i-2]\ -\  y[i-3]\,y[i-1]\ +\ y[i-2]^2}$
Questions:


what is known about sequences with constant cross-ratio, e.g. the solution of the above recurrence?
have these sequence been encountered/investigated before?



As usual, define the cross-ratio of four numbers as
$$ CR([a:b:c:d]) := \frac{(a-c)(b-d)}{(a-d)(b-c)}. \tag1 $$
This quantity is translation invariant, thus given the first differences,
define their cross ratio
$$ CR([y_0:y_1:y_2]) := CR([0: y_0: y_0+y_1: y_0+y_1+y_2]). \tag2 $$
Given a sequence $y_0,y_1,y_2,\dots,$ require that
$ CR([y_n:y_{n-1}:y_{n-2}]) $ be constant for all $n$.
This implies that this sequence satisfies the recurrence
$$ y_n=\frac{ y_{n-3}y_{n-1}^2}{y_{n-3}y_{n-2}-y_{n-3}y_{n-1}+y_{n-2}^2}.
 \tag 3 $$
The question is


what is known about sequences with constant cross-ratio, e.g.
the solution of the above recurrence?
have these sequence been encountered/investigated before?


The answer is that the complete solution is known and these sequences have
been encountered before but in a reciprocal form. That is, define
the reciprocal sequence $ x_n := 1/y_{n+1} $ assuming no $ y_n=0. $
Verify that the new sequence satisfies $x_{-1}=y_0, x_0=y_1, x_1=y_2$ and
the recurrence
$$ x_n = x_{n-1}\frac{x_{n-1}x_{n-2}+x_{n-1}x_{n-3}-x_{n-2}^2}{x_{n-2}^2}.
\tag4 $$
Define the constant values
$$ s := 1-\frac{x_1x_{-1}}{x_0^2},\quad t := \frac{x_1+x_{-1}}{x_0}-s.
\tag5 $$
Verify with elementary algebra that the sequence also satisfies the
linear recurrence with constant coefficients
$$ x_{n-1} - tx_n + x_{n+1}  = sx_0. \tag6 $$
Examples of such sequences in the OEIS are
A000466,
A101265,
A011900 and many others.
The general solution of equation $(6)$ is
$$ x_n = c\big(\cos(b) - \cos(2bn+a)\big),\quad t = 2\cos(2b) \tag7 $$
where $a,b,c$ are complex constants. A limiting case when $a=0,$
$c=2d/b^2$ as $b\to 0$ is
$$ x_n = d(4n^2-1) = d\,A000466(n). \tag8 $$
Another limiting case when $a=-\frac3{4c}-\frac{\pi}2,$
$ b=-\frac1{4c}+\frac{\pi}2$ as $c\to\infty$ is
OEIS A001057.
